# C++ abstract function objects result in confusing behavior when used with std::accumulate

Tags: c++, inheritance

If I have a pure virtual functor and its implementation such as:

```
class A {
    public:
        virtual int operator()(int& k, int& k2) = 0;

    public:
        virtual ~A() = default;
        void DoStuff() {
            std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
            int k = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, std::ref(*this));
            // ...
        }
};

class B : public A {
    protected:
        int operator()(int &k, int &k2) override {
            return k + k2;
        }
};

void DoSomething() {
    B b;
    b.DoStuff();
}
```

I have the following observations:

1. The last argument of the `std::accumulate` call needs to be wrapped with std::ref, which is an extremely weird place for it to appear - as it should almost exclusively be used inside function bindings. Even if I refactor `DoStuff()` to a free function, it is still needed - meaning that I cannot simply put `*this` for the class method or a regular instance of `A` (in the form of `B()`) for the free function. In both cases compilation of `DoSomething()` will fail with the message of `invalid abstract parameter` for the functor argument, despite I explicitly defining the non-abstract object `b`. If I don't declare the `operator()` of `A` pure virtual and instead provide it with a definition, the `std::accumulate` call will invoke the version in `A`. In general, it seems like somehow those STL functions that require other functions as argument (`std::accumulate`, `std::transform`, etc) will not leverage the vtable for functor class resolution when it's not wrapped with `std::ref`.
2. If I make the scope of `operator()` in class `A` (the base class) `protected`, compilation of the class method `DoStuff()` will fail, claiming that `operator() is protected within this context`. This directly goes against the definition of `protected` scope, as it should allow access of class methods and variables (as well as inherited ones) within the same class. Note that making the inherited class's `operator()` `protected` is completely fine, and the compiler can resolve to the correct implementation of the `operator()`. In general, it seems like somehow those STL functions that require other functions as argument break the class scope resolution. Note that this observation still holds after I use `std::ref` to wrap the argument.

Could someone explain, from the compiler's perspective, what is the reasoning behind those observations?

Explicit questions from the observations:

- The implementation class `B` should be copyable and assignable as-is, so why is `reference_wrapper` needed?
- It should be fine to invoke external functions with member variables or member functions inside a member function, regardless of scope. Why is the function argument exempt from the visibility scope resolution?
- This doesn't look like undefined behavior. Feeding function objects to `std::accumulate` should be well defined and encouraged. I tried the code with multiple compilers (GCC, clang, MSVC) and they all produced the same results. If these behaviors are intended, are they documented somewhere in the C++ Standard as an exception towards the default inheritance and visibility rules?

Answer (score 2):

## Observation #1

`std::accumulate` overload that takes a function object and treats it like a value type that is `CopyAssignable` and `CopyConstructible`. See [cppreference for accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

OLD/INCORRECT: In your case, I think the compiler is trying to make a copy of `*this` which has type `A&`. The resulting copy would have type `A` which is abstract.

EDIT: actually, I think the template is deducing the type of `BinaryOperation` as `A` and trying to instantiate `std::accumulate(..., A op)`. I incorrectly said that the type of `*this` is `A&`, while it is actually `A`. Here is the error I am seeing when using [cpp.sh](https://cpp.sh):

`/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_numeric.h: In substitution of 'template<class _InputIterator, class _Tp, class _BinaryOperation> _Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Tp = int; _BinaryOperation = A]':`

In this case, using `std::ref` is the correct solution because it creates a `std::reference_wrapper` which refers to the original (concrete) object. `std::accumulate` is instantiated with `BinaryOperation` = `std::reference_wrapper<A>` which is concrete and `CopyConstructable`. See [cppreference for reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

## Observation #2

You are passing a reference `A&`, in an `std::reference_wrapper<A>`, to `std::accumulate` which attempts to invoke it by calling `operator()`, which is protected. This is the same situation as the following example:

Declare a normal protected member function:

```
    protected:
       void DoProtected() { }
```

Inside `DoStuff()` call a non-member function:

```
       void DoStuff() {
            Foo(*this);
        }
```

Non-member function attempts to use `DoProtected`:

```
static void Foo(A& bar) {
    bar.DoProtected();
}
```

Resulting in `error: 'void A::DoProtected()' is protected within this context`.

If you want `operator()` to be protected, you can write code inside `class A` which calls the protected operator:

```
            int k = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, 
              [this](int& k, int& k2){ return (*this)(k, k2); });
```

### What about `B::operator()`

The reason it's OK to make `B::operator()` protected is that std::accumulate sees an `std::reference_wrapper<A>` and calls `A::operator()` which is public. C++ allows overriding public virtual methods with protected ones, but I don't know the rationale behind this.